# HasOne relationship cannot be set to null inside ForEach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Say there is a model that has entries. Each entry has a currency. I want to update the currency like so:

```
var model = await _dbContext.Models
    .Include(x => x.Entries) 
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.ToString().Equals(command.Id), cancellationToken);

model.Name = command.Name;

command.Entries.ForEach(x =>
{
    var entry = _dbContext.Entries
        .Find(Guid.Parse(x.Id));

    var currency = _dbContext.Currencies
        .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id.Equals(x.CurrencyId));

    entry.Currency = currency;
});

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Here is how the currency relationship is defiend:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>()
    .HasOne<Currency>(x => x.Currency)
    .WithMany();
```

I am debugging a problem where currency can be assigned a value but not null. E.g.

```
command.Entries.ForEach(x =>
{
    var entry = _dbContext.Entries
        .Find(Guid.Parse(x.Id));

    entry.Currency = null;
});
```

won't set the currency to null but this works:

```
command.Entries.ForEach(x =>
{
    var entry = _dbContext.Entries
        .Find(Guid.Parse(x.Id));

    var currency = ...

    entry.Currency = currency;
});
```

Currency is updated correctly. Now when I do the update outside of ForEach it works:

```
var entry = _dbContext.Entries.Find(Guid.Parse(".."));

entry.Currency = null;

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

So ForEach seems to be the issue. Any ideas why? It's strange that the currency can be updated to a value but cannot be set to null inside ForEach.

Comment: `ForEach` isn't a LINQ command and isn't translated to SQL. It's a List<T> method that does nothing more than what `foreach(var item in thatList)` would do **but** the lambda is a separate scope. `entry` doesn't exist outside that lambda

Comment: The code is *very* slow because it loads entities one by one. You could replace `ForEach` with `_dbContext.Entries.Where(e=>listOfIds.Contains(e.Id))` to generate a `ID in (@id1, @id2, @id3,....)` clause. If you used `Inlude(e=>e.Currency)` you wouldn't need to load `Currency` separately. Even now, you can load it explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main cause of the issue is that the `Currency` is *navigation* property, and is not loaded automatically (see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)), thus has `null` value and setting it to `null` has no effect, since the change tracker does not see a change in that property.

It can be fixed with simple `ThenInclude` to eager load it when retrieving the main data:

```cs
.Include(x => x.Entries)
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Currency)
```

Everything else could stay as is.

Comment: I feel the need to facepalm. Leaky abstractions and all that

Comment: I think an explanation why setting to `null` sometimes worked (as in the last snippet) is that the adhering currency happened to have been loaded into the context, so relationship fixup had taken place. It's even likely (though not mentioned) that setting `null` succeeded in a growing number of cases as the loop progressed.